# How to create a "for" loop to add not only a value but also an indentifier. Android, Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, loops, for-loop

Let's say i have an example array of integers, but I don't know the length of the array (it gets added to with shared preferences and will grow in size each time the app is run):

```
int[] testArray = new int[UNKNOWN LENGTH];
```

And i want to create some int names with the values from the array. 
ie.

```
int test1 = testArray[1]; 

int test2 = testArray[2];

int test3 = testArray[3];

....

int test999 = testArray[999];
```

> > Let's assume this is the length and final value, although in the real app we don't know.

So, to get started, i have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
int test1 = testArray[i] }
```

However, this only will add values i=0 and upwards to the testArray[i]. 
ie.

```
test1 = testArray[1];
test1 = testArray[2];
test1 = testArray[3];
```

Can i also make the "test1" change to test2, test3 etc. by using the loop and i?

Ie.

```
int testi = testArray[i].
```

Of course this line of code will not work for obvious reasons, but is there a way to do such a thing with an array and loop??
Or do i need to resort to an array list, or perhaps something else?

Comment: why don't you just use that array values? it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Funny, this errors indicates that you are fighting to understand what compilation and programming are. Actually, I am looking for a simple way to explain you what's wrong in your way of thinking but find it quite difficult. I would really recommend that you take time with your CS teacher to talk about this. A small indication maybe : it's not because i is a variable that testi is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data Structure to store a set of values of unknown length)**

```
// Create a Vector and populate it with elements
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.add(new Integer(1));
    vector.add(new Integer(2));
    vector.add(new Integer(3));
 // elements() method returns an Enumeration of Vector's elements
```

**Adding to Shared Preferences**

```
Enumeration vectorElementsEnum = vector.elements();
int counter=0;
     String arrayName = "myArr";
     while(vectorElementsEnum.hasMoreElements())
    {
    editor.putInt(arrayName + "_" + i, vectorElementsEnum.nextElement());
    editor.commit();
    count++;  
    } 
   editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", counter); 
   editor.commit();
```

**Retrieving from  Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
Integer array[] = new Integer [size];  
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
  array[i] = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_" + i, -1);
```

Finally having something like var1=arr[1],var2=arr[2], etc is uncalled for because var1 will be same as arr[1], so why have data replicated?
Hope the above implementation suits your need.

Comment: Yeah another really good suggestion. I'll give this a try before I think about incorporating a macro!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try some simple explanation.

When you write an assignment statement like :

```
int a = b;
```

the left hand side of the assignment is your variable : 'a'. This variable is has a name, for humans, but for the computer this name will not be kept. It will be transformed into some location into the machines memory, let's say RAM address 435643.

the right hand side is the value of this assignment. It is evaluated : this means every variable it contains will be replaced by its value during runtime, when the program is run.

As you can see, variable substitution only occurs on the right hand side of an assignment, not on the left hand side of it.

That's the first part of the explanation.

The second is tied to what a symbol is in programming. If you declare a variable like :

```
 int i;
```

this means that i is now a known symbol for the compiler. Everytime 'i' will occur in a right hand side expression, it will be replaced by its value. Like in

```
int j = i;
```

This means that the variable j will have the value of 'i' at the time is statement is executed. It doesn't mean the variable j is an alias for i. If we write

```
i = i +1;
```

then i is incremented, but j will remain the same.

It doesn't mean neither that everything containing a 'i' will be replaced by the value of i. And if you now declare a variable like :

```
int testi;
```

the 'testi' is a symbol on its own. It is not a composition of 2 symbols like : 'test' + 'i'.

So, to sum up : on the left handside of an assignment, you *define* symbols. And they are not composed.
On the right hand side, you *use* symbols : that's where they will be replaced by their value.

---

Ultimately, what @cyborg86pl explained is that you seem to find the variable name testArray[0] not very handy, and would like to call it test0. But that's really not a good point. If you want to give a name to this value, then why don't you just use testArray[0], that's already quite a good name to designate this value. You don't need a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time to understand what you are trying to do. Like Snicolas said, your design is probably very wrong.

Anyway, you could try to use a Map

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    map.put("test"+i, testArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a design problem, even not a code problem. I believe it's a general CS problem to understand what a variable is, means and can be used to, what's the difference between evaluation at runtime and compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to Scala, which is also JVM-based and runs smoothly on Android,
then you can use macros. Assuming that UNKNOWN_LENGTH is a number known at compile time (e.g. replaced by a script),

```
my_macro { val testArray = new Array[Int](UNKNOWN_LENGTH) }
```

And in another project, define the macro

```
def my_macro (x: Unit): Unit = macro my_macro_impl 
def my_macro_impl(c: Context)(x: Expr[Unit]): Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._
  val seqs = x match {
    case q"val $array = new Array[Int]($a)" => x::(for(i <- 0 until a.toInt)
       yield q"val test$i = testArray(i)").toList
    case _ => x
  }
  c.Expr[Unit](Block(seqs))
}
```

If anyone knows about macros, he/she can correct my code as I have no experience using them.

Comment: Now we're talking. A macro. Good suggestion. 

To the other suggestions. I don't have an issue with understanding what a variable is, or how they work in the craaazy world of computer science lol, i was merely trying to make explain what i want to do... which was difficult! I'm sorry if it was a little vague, my bad. But this guy gets it... thanks for the suggestion! : )

Comment: I think this approach is useful if you have other macros to call these variables.